# Google Custom Search in ASP.NET and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined"

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-custom-search

I found semi similar questions but none of them shed a light on my scenario, so I hope this can help me and anyone else experiencing the same issue. Long story short, I'm trying to implement a (Full page) Google Custom Search box in a ASP.NET (Web Forms) CMS using this Bootstrap solution: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/full-screen-search

I created the Bootstrap pop-up box with my Google Custom Search embedded in it as a .ascx constrol, it's working okay but I'm getting a JS error in console when I click the search icon and I think the problem is because my ASP.NET CMS already has a postback form, which complicates the integration since there will be a nested `<form></form>` within my ASP.NET `<form runat="server"></form>` which is not valid HTML and that's why I'm getting a JS error in console saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined.

This is the code that Google wants me to paste in the `<body>` which I included in my custom control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GoogleCustomSearch.ascx.cs" Inherits="GoogleCustomSearch" %>

<!-- Google custom search in a pop-up -->
<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right google-custom-search-box'>
    <li>
        <a href="#search">
            <span id="searchGlyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="search">
    <button type="button" class="close">×</button>
    <script>
      (function() {
        var cx = 'my-cx-number-123456';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
            '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

And this is my JS that fires the click to pop-up:

```
// Google search pop-up
    $(function () {
        $('a[href="#search"]').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#search').addClass('open');
            $('body').addClass('gsc-overflow-hidden');
            $('#gsc-i-id1').focus();
            $('#gsc-i-id1').attr('placeholder', 'Search...');
        });

        $('#search, #search button.close').on('click keyup', function(event) {
            if (event.target == this || event.target.className == 'close' || event.keyCode == 27) {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                $('body').removeClass('gsc-overflow-hidden');
            }
        });
    });
```

The code above creates the nested `<form>` tag which I'm trying to avoid. So, what's the best alternative solution/code to avoid this issue?

By the way, I want to display the search results in the same pop-up and for that the "Full width" Look and feel is selected in GCS dashboard.

Comment: Can you copy the actual HTML output for your page (view source) into a jsfiddle or something. I'm a little confused as to what's going on here.

Comment: I found this article explaining the same issue but the article suggest a search result page instead of displaying the search result on the same page, that's where I'm getting confused as how to proceed: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Implementing-Search-in-ASP-NET-with-Google-Custom-Search.aspx

Comment: You best bet might be to use an iframe then and load up the search results in that (like navigating to another link, but with only part of the page)

Comment: Hmmm... that's not a perfect solution but also not a bad idea. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @MattiPrice thank you for the suggestion. The iframe solution works but I'm having difficulties to make the embedded form input field focused with jQuery.  Before Embedding the iframe I could control the field with `$("#gsc-i-id1").focus();` but not anymore.

Comment: yeahhhh unfortunately that's the main drawback. Due to security reasons, you won't be able to access the content inside the iframe if it's coming from a different domain. You can have your search textbox on your own page, and then the search results piped to the iframe.

Comment: The content is a page with Google custom search code and it's on my domain. I was able to access the input field using `contents()` so this worked for me: `$('#gcs-embed-wrapper').contents().find('#gsc-i-id1').focus();` .. **gcs-embed-wrapper** is the iframe Id and **gsc-i-id1** is the input field.

Comment: Oh perfect! Then yeah that will work. Glad you got it figured out!